# How to join table in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

`T1 table`

```
+-----------+------------------+
| cookie_id |    impression    |
+-----------+------------------+
|       123 |          6/17/15 |
|       123 |          6/18/15 |
|       123 |          6/18/15 |
|       234 |          6/20/15 |
|       234 |          6/22/15 |
+-----------+------------------+

T2 table
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| cookie_id |   HP    | search  |  book   |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|       123 | 6/17/15 |         |         |
|       123 | 6/18/15 |         |         |
|       123 |         | 6/18/15 |         |
|       123 |         |         | 6/19/15 |
|       234 | 6/23/15 |         |         |
|       234 |         | 6/25/15 |         |
|       234 |         |         | 6/29/15 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

we'd like to join T1 and T2 as the expected result as below T3 table :

```
+-----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| cookie_id | impression |   HP    | search  |  book   |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|       123 | 6/17/15    |         |         |         |
|       123 | 6/18/15    |         |         |         |
|       123 | 6/18/15    |         |         |         |
|       123 |            | 6/17/15 |         |         |
|       123 |            | 6/18/15 |         |         |
|       123 |            |         | 6/18/15 |         |
|       123 |            |         |         | 6/19/15 |
|       234 | 6/20/15    |         |         |         |
|       234 | 6/22/15    |         |         |         |
|       234 |            | 6/23/15 |         |         |
|       234 |            |         | 6/25/15 |         |
|       234 |            |         |         | 6/29/15 |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: what did you try? And can you format your question so that it becomes clearer what you want?

Comment: @luksch hi, i formatted. could you help me?

Comment: This is not a join but a UNION

Comment: @luksch  thank you so much ! but do you know how to union the table

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/375e6/2

```
SELECT cookie_id, impression, null,null, null
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT cookie_id, null as impression, hp, search,book
FROM t2
```

Comment: you created even a fiddle for the guy. That is really worth my up-vote :) Do you know a tool to easily generate the "CREATE TABLE" statements for fiddles?

Comment: thank you. No, I don't know any tool to get `CREATE TABLE` I do it manually for such small tables like these.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you seems to want to UNION the tables: This will do it, but it may not be what you really really need...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT cookie_id, 
            "" AS impression, 
            HP, 
            search, 
            book 
     FROM T1)
     UNION
    (SELECT cookie_id, 
            impression, 
            "" AS HP, 
            "" AS search, 
            "" AS book
     FROM T2)
    ) a
ORDER BY cookie_id;
```

This is out of my head, maybe I made a typo or something.